# WSL2 Windows 11 After upgrade - Ubuntu 18.04 on WSL2 has no internet "No Route to Host"

Tags: networking, 18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

After upgrading the windows 11, my WSL2 Ubuntu 18.04 has no internet access. I get the error "No Route to Host". I double checked my resolv.conf as displayed below:

root@~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf nameserver 8.8.8.8 nameserver 8.8.4.4

What could be wrong and why does this ALWAYS happen?

Comment: Read `man ip ip-route`. Look at `ip route`. Do you have a `default` route?Look at the logs!  `sudo  journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: nothing in the logs

Comment: @waltinator WSL doesn't set up logging, nor use `journalctl` (without additional, albiet hacky, effort).